# Morphia, Embed Mongo and Spring. Address already in use

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia, spring-mongo

I am trying use MongoDB, Morphia and Spring and test it, so I started use Embedded Mongo.

When I had only one DAO to persist I did not had any problem with my tests, however, in some cases I needed use more than one DAO, and in that cases my injected Datasore give me an problem: addr already in use.

My Spring Test Database Configuration is this:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseMockConfig {

private static final int PORT = 12345;

private MongodConfigBuilder configBuilder;

private MongodExecutable mongodExecutable;

private MongodProcess mongodProcess;


@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public MongodExecutable getMongodExecutable() {
    return this.mongodExecutable;
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public MongodProcess mongodProcess() {
    return this.mongodProcess;
}

@Bean
public IMongodConfig getMongodConfig() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    if (this.configBuilder == null) {
        configBuilder = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION).net(new Net(PORT, Network.localhostIsIPv6()));
    }

    return this.configBuilder.build();
}

@Autowired
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Datastore datastore(IMongodConfig mongodConfig) throws IOException {

    MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();

    this.mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);

    this.mongodProcess = mongodExecutable.start();

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", PORT);

    return new Morphia().createDatastore(mongoClient, "morphia");
}

@Autowired
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public EventDAO eventDAO(final Datastore datastore) {
    return new EventDAO(datastore);
}

@Autowired
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public EditionDAO editionDAO(final Datastore datastore) {
    return new EditionDAO(datastore);
}
}
```

And my DAO classes are similar to that

```
@Repository
public class EventDAO {

private final BasicDAO<Event, ObjectId> basicDAO;

@Autowired
public EventDAO(final Datastore datastore) {
    this.basicDAO = new BasicDAO<>(Event.class, datastore);
}
...
}
```

My test class is similar to that:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppMockConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class EventDAOTest {

@Autowired
private EventDAO eventDAO;

@Autowired
private MongodExecutable mongodExecutable;

@Autowired
private MongodProcess mongodProcess;

@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedEx = ExpectedException.none();

@After
public void tearDown() {

    this.mongodProcess.stop();
    this.mongodExecutable.stop();
}
...
}
```

I use prototype scope to solve problem with singleton and make sure that my mock database is clean when I start my test, after that I stop mongod process and mongod executable.

However since I need use more than one DAO I receive that error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'editionDAO' defined in class br.com.mymusicapp.spring.DatabaseMockConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore]: : 
Error creating bean with name 'datastore' defined in class br.com.mymusicapp.spring.DatabaseMockConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore]: 
Factory method 'datastore' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Could not start process: ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:12345
2015-01-04T01:05:04.128-0200 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
```

I know what the error means, I just do not know how can I design my Configuration to solve that. As last option I am considering install a localhost MongoDB just for tests, however I think could be a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is based on the [embedded mongod by flapdoodle](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo), right?

If you want to run multiple tests in parallel (could be changed via JUnit annotations, but it's probably faster in parallel), you cannot use a single, hardcoded port. Instead, let the embedded process [select an available port automatically](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo#use-free-server-port).

Comment: I was getting random IOExceptions, now it makes sanse. Thanks!